# how to make this loop only write the second if once when all no matches are found

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I have an array of 5 cleanest cities (names) in my country. Then there's a prompt where a user enters their city and if the city is found in the array, "wooray" is printed on the console.

If the city isn't found, "your city stinks" is printed instead.

Since the names of the cities are in an array, I made a `for` loop to loop through all the names, comparing these to find a match.

Its working, but one problem is that even when a user enters a city that's present in the array, if that city is, let's say the 3rd item in the array, all of the following is printed in order:

> Your city stinks
>   Your city stinks
>   Wooray

Only then will the loop break. I need to only send "wooray" without the "stinks" and only send the "stinks" when it has been confirmed to the end of the array that the city isn't there.

My script is as follows:

```
var cityToCheck = prompt("your humble city?");
var cleanestCities = [ "Bulawayo", "gweru", "Gwanda", "falls", "plumtree" ];
var found = "no";
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (cityToCheck == cleanestCities[i]) {
        found = "yes";
        console.log("wooray");
        break;
    };
    if(found = "no") {
        console.log("your city stinks");
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a tip, @Cool_berserker -- for your near future of mastering JavaScript, if it is to be -- `cleanestCities.includes(cityToCheck)` will return `true` if the value (city name, referenced by `cityToCheck` in your case) is in the array, and `false` if it is not. Courtesy of the ECMAScript (JavaScript is an ECMAScript-compliant language) language which provides the `include` function. Read more about arrays on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: My friend you're absolutely genius to remind me of the array.include() trick. I have made the shortest code possible (probably) for what i needed. It didn't even need a loop, only an if statement. Thanks pal

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't want to write an answer because I wasn't sure you wanted a general solution for the kind of cases you're dealing with or you wanted to just make your code work (which is of course an absolutely valid goal, too), and there are answers already that tell you how to fix the code above, so you have best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good only search the city in loop and if city found then change the `found` flag and based on the `found`, log something in console.

like this:

```js
var cityToCheck = prompt("your humble city?");
var cleanestCities = [ "Bulawayo", "gweru", "Gwanda", "falls", "plumtree" ];
var found = "no";
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (cityToCheck == cleanestCities[i]) {
        found = "yes";
        break;
    }
}

if(found == "yes")
    console.log("wooray");
else if (found == "no")
    console.log("your city stinks");
```

I also suggest you use `found` as boolean.
I mean this:

```js
var cityToCheck = prompt("your humble city?");
var cleanestCities = [ "Bulawayo", "gweru", "Gwanda", "falls", "plumtree" ];
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (cityToCheck == cleanestCities[i]) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(found)
    console.log("wooray");
else
    console.log("your city stinks");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
if(found = "no"){
```

The reason this is a problem is because JavaScript is evaluating `found = "no"` as an expression assigning the value `"no"` to `found`; since it's an assignment, it will return `true`. You need a second `=` sign to check for equality:

```
if(found == "no"){
```

Take a smaller example:

```
var i;
if(i == 5) console.log("i is 5");
if(i = 5) console.log("Oops! I just set i to 5");
```

Your output would be:

> Oops! I just set i to 5

Edit:

The other thing you may consider is pulling the if(found == "no") out of the loop. That way, it only checks once, at the end of the loop.

If your city is "falls" for example, you will get 3 "your city stinks" because it's checking the 3 cities before "falls" first - none of which match "falls".

Comment: "*since it's an assignment, it will return true*" more precisely, assignments return the assigned value. So `found = "no"` will return `"no"` which is a truthy and makes the `if` body execute. However `someVar = 0` will return zero which is falsy and `if (someVar = 0)` will never go inside the `if` body.

Comment: I changed to if (found == "no") and its still not working, test it

Comment: @Cool_berserker the other thing you may consider is pulling the if(found == "no") out of the loop. That way, it only checks once. If your city is "falls" for example, you will get 3 "your city stinks" because it's checking the 3 cities before "falls" first - none of which match "falls".

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(found == "no") {
        console.log("your city stinks");
    }
```

this if statement should be outside of the for loop.

but if you want shorter version

```
var cityToCheck = "Gwanda"

var cleanestCities = ["Bulawayo","gweru","Gwanda","falls","plumtree"];

console.log((cleanestCities.indexOf(cityToCheck) > -1) ? "wooray":"your city    stinks");
```

Answer (score 0):

take "if (found...)" outside of for loop.

```
var cleanestCities = [ "Bulawayo", "gweru", "Gwanda", "falls", "plumtree" ];
var cityToCheck = prompt("your humble city?");
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < cleanestCities.length; i++) {
    if (cityToCheck == cleanestCities[i]) {
        found = true;
        break;
    };
}

if(found) {
    console.log("wooray");
}
else {
     console.log("your city stinks");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet

```
var cityToCheck = prompt("your humble city?");
var cleanestCities = ["Bulawayo", "gweru", "Gwanda", "falls", "plumtree"];
if(cleanestCities.indexOf(cityToCheck) > -1) {
    console.log("wooray");
} else {
    console.log("your city stinks");
}
```